# Matplotlib Name points on plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, annotations

I have searched and found that using  annotate in matplotlib for jupyter, we can name the x and y of a point.

I have retried doing as you suggested.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def fit_data():

    fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(20,6))
    plt.subplot(111)

    data1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : list(range(11)), 
                   "R" : list(range(11)),
                   "Theta" : list(range(11))})

    plt.scatter(data1['R'], data1['Theta'],  marker='o', color='b', s=15)

    for i, row in data1.iterrows():
        plt.annotate(row["ID"], xy=(row["R"],row["Theta"]))

    plt.xlabel('R',size=20)
    plt.ylabel('Theta',size=20)

    plt.show()
    plt.close()

fit_data()
```

It still doesn't take the ID from my data. It is still plotting an arbitrary plot. 
[this is the image after using the revised code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9olz.png)

My data is as follows

```
1 19.177    24.642
2 9.398     12.774
3 9.077     12.373
4 15.287    19.448
5 4.129     5.41
6 2.25      3.416
7 11.674    15.16
8 10.962    14.469
9 1.924     3.628
10 2.087    3.891
11 9.706    13.186
```

Comment: The syntax for `annotate` is `ax.annotate("text", xy=(x,y))`. Instead of `"text"` you can use your ID. Feel free to provide a code with your attempt and an explanation at which point you are stuck.

Comment: I have added the code. I need the points to display the ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the confusion comes from the fact that while `scatter` can plot all points at once, while an annotation is a singular object. You would hence need one `annotation` per row in the dataframe.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : list(range(6)),          # Do not copy this part.
                   "R" : [5,4,1,2,3,4],            # Use your own data 
                   "Theta" : [20,15,40,60,51,71]}) # instead.

fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(20,6))
plt.subplot(111)

plt.scatter(df['R'], df['Theta'],  marker='o', color='b', s=15)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    plt.annotate(row["ID"], xy=(row["R"],row["Theta"]))

plt.xlabel('R',size=20)
plt.ylabel('Theta',size=20)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. The ID that it marks is from '0' not from my data set. If I have  a large data set say 100 odd points, then do I have to do the  'df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : list(range(6)),  "R" : [5,4,1,2,3,4],
                   "Theta" : [20,15,40,60,51,71]})' for all those points.

Comment: No. I created a dataset `df` here because I do not have your data. In your case you will use your own data of course.

Comment: I have edited the question putting in the trail data set I am using. It has to use the ID mentioned in the file and not an arbitrary one. How do I go about doing that

Comment: Instead of the dataset `df` I used here, you need to use your own dataset `data1`.

Comment: Pardon me I didn't follow. Could you please explain.

Comment: You open a new file in your editor. You copy your code down to the line `data1.columns = ...` into that file. You take the code from this answer starting from the line `fig = plt.figure(....)` and copy it below. You then replace every occurance of `df` with `data1`. Then you run the code.

Comment: I have edited the code and replotted. I have a problem. The images are attached

Comment: I think I've done everything I can to explain that you need to use *your own data*, instead of the data from my answer. If that does not help, maybe you want to take a step back and go through some python programming and pandas tutorials.

Comment: I have edited my main question and have rewritten the code to match my data but still it is not taking the ID i have from 1. It is naming the ID from 0 to 10 not from 1 to 11. Could you please look at the code again one last time and let me know. Thank you.

Comment: `list(range(11))` starts at `0` and goes till `10`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you